# What are the Korean DFS Radar Wi-Fi channels regulations?

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11

I couldn't find the answer from Google search.

The closest was: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/U-NII
(The Unlicensed National Information Infrastructure (U-NII) radio band is part of the radio frequency spectrum used by IEEE-802.11a devices and by many wireless ISPs.)

In the column for Korea, there are 'No' and 'Yes'. I assume they just indicate whether it is a DFS channel or not.

What is the CAC time of waiting for each of these radar channels in Korea?

I want some more reliable official source about this regulation.

The Wikipedia reference link http://www.rra.go.kr/join/databoard/law/view.jsp?lw_type=3&lw_seq=187 (Korea Frequency Distribution Table 2008.12.31 (in Korean)) is broken.

Comment: Unfortunately, resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

Using wireless reg db from:
git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/sforshee/wireless-regdb.git

```
country KR: DFS-JP                                  
        (2402 - 2482 @ 40), (20)                    
        (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (20), AUTO-BW           
        (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (20), DFS, AUTO-BW      
        (5490 - 5710 @ 160), (30), DFS              
        (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (30)                    
        # 60 GHz band channels 1-4,                 
        # ref: http://www.law.go.kr/%ED%96%89%EC%A0%95%EA%B7%9C%EC%B9%99/%EB%AC%B4%EC%84%A0%EC%84%A4%EB%B9%84%EA%B7%9C%EC%B9%99                                                                                    
        (57000 - 66000 @ 2160), (43)
```